# Bad response from GAE remote_api, memcache, and Golang

Tags: google-app-engine, go, memcached

I'm trying to do a simple `memcache.Delete(c, KEY)` in a `remote_api` call, and I'm getting a weird error:

```
bad response 400; body: ""
```

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Were you able to get any other services (e.g., datastore) working with the same context or is the issue limited to memcache? If the problem was global, did you enable remote_api url handler in your app.yaml?